# Bringing a Split View Into An Existing Tab Bar App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am currently working on a **Tab Bar** related application.

I would like to introduce a **Split View** to be used as **Preferences** data.

Firstly, can it be done?

Secondly, are there guides out there which may show me the direction?

Pete

PS: The application is iPad based.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the rootViewController

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = xx
```